# PHP & bash; Linux; Compile my own function

Tags: php, linux, bash

I would like to make my own program but I have no idea how.. for example I want to make a typical 'Hello $user' program.

So..

```
├── hi
│   ├── hi.sh
│   ├── hi_to.sh
```

---

**hi.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
~/hi/hi_to.sh $1
```

---

**hi_to.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    echo "\nHellO ".$argv[1]."\n";
?>
```

---

**Run it in terminal:**

```
me:~/hi  
→ ./hi.sh User

HellO User
```

---

**and my question is: how to compile all this files into one bash program?**

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "compile all this files into one bash program"?

Comment: I want to make one bash command, like 'cd, cal & so on..'. In this case 'hello' command. not simple to add an alias in '.bashrc'..

Comment: Make a directory called "~/bin". Edit your `~/.bashrc` file so that your PATH includes `~/bin`. Copy your script into `~/bin`, renaming it to "hi" (without `.sh`). After you restart your session or source `~/.bashrc` from the command line, the new PATH will take effect. Then you can type "hi User" at the command line *et voilà*.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. If you want it in one script then you put it in one script in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we understand the question, because you could just call hi_to.sh like this:

```
./hi_to.sh user
```

And it would run like you want, getting rid of the first sh script.

Comment: I've made one more complicated script with php&bash and here I've tried to make a simple example for explaining what I want..

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line points to the correct php executable
2. You don't have to call the script hi.php, just call it `hi`
3. Make your script file executable ( e.g. via `chmod u+x path/to/hi` or `chmod a+rx path/to/hi`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)
4. Make sure the file is within the search [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) for the user/accounts that are supposed to use your script (without typing the absolute path)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could see this 'combined' is by using a here-doc, which basically causes the first script to generate the second, then execute it:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOF > /tmp/$$.php
<?php
    \$string="$1";
    echo "\nHellO ". \$string ."\n";
?>
EOF

/usr/bin/php -q /tmp/$$.php
retval=$?

rm /tmp/$$.php

exit $retval
```

In that example, `$1` will expand to the first argument. I have escaped the other variables (that are related only to PHP), which PHP will expand when it runs. `$$` in a shell script just expands to the PID of the script, the actual temporary file is going to be something like `/tmp/1234.php`. `mktemp(1)` is a much safer way to make a temporary file name that is more resistant to link attacks and collisions.

It also saves the exit status of PHP in `retval` , which is then returned when the script exits.

The resulting file will look like this (assuming the first argument to the shell script is `foo`):

```
<?php
   $string="foo";
   echo "\nHello " . $string . "\n";
?>
```

This is kind of an icky demonstration for how to use bash to write other scripts, but at least demonstrates that its possible. Its the only way I could think of to 'combine' (as you indicated) the two scripts that you posted.

Comment: You could do that without a temporary file: (@ indicates a newline since we can't format comments) `php -q /dev/stdin <<EOF@<?php echo "hello\n"; ?>@EOF`

Comment: @Dennis, if you want to edit my answer to add that, feel free :) I'm relatively sure (at this point) the OP will want to see the results of the here-doc in a file for debugging, especially due to the need to escape variables that php, not bash should expand.

Comment: No, I was just offering a way to have things more "compiled" as it were. I'm not advocating either approach. Doing things such as this is just asking for trouble.